# What slide will give me the fastest taming speed on Ark?

Tags: ark-survival-evolved

OK so I'm going to be playing Ark later. But this time I want to play without the cheats and all that stuff. But, I am very impatient. So what side of the slider will give me the fastest taming speed and the highest harvest amount? If it helps any, I'm playing this on Xbox One.

Comment: Pretty sure taming speed is all the way to the right, but you can also manually enter numbers over the slider cap for some settings. Not sure about harvest amount. You can alter them on each game load though, so you can test as much as you want.